# How to share from android to a Windows PC asynchronously?

Tags: windows, phone, sharing

I often have the case when I find something interesting on my phone but need to actually use it on my laptop, but it is currently offline.

This my be a Windows software or a web page.

What would be the best way to share such information (a URL to make it easier) and do that it is displayed on my PC when I am back online (as a popup, or alert)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is strictly pages from a browser you can use the "send tab to device" feature of [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/send-tab-firefox-desktop-other-devices) and [Chrome](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-share-tabs-between-devices-google-chrome/). Other browsers might have similar functions.

Answer (score 1):

I have two options:

1. From your phone browser share the URL to your e-mails address. You will later work on that when you are on your PC
2. If you use FireFox or Chrome on your phone you can create a bookmark folder called "watch later" and save the content to that folder. You then need to sync your phone browser with your PC browser

Answer (score 0):

Answers so far are good. You could also get a free [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/) account, which gives 2gB storage.

That will synch when you log in to your laptop. I use it for two way file synch of my Keepass password file, plus a few other files.

Comment: I self-host a complete file-sharing system so this is not a problem. The thing is that I do not want to share files but URLs.